# Suitable platform for a 2D simulator using java

Tags: java, simulator, java-2d, jmonkeyengine

I have to do my final year project and I'm planning to use a visual simulator to simulate it. So I have to create a basic simulator and the program would be run in java. But I have a problem as to what to use to create the simulator. Should I use jmonkey or java2D or java 3D. What I would want is a basic 2d simulator. Please help me out. It would be better if it's java based as I do all my development using java

thanks,

ps :- Im planning to do a simulation on human movement within a building in a panic situation. so what i would need is a 2D view of maybe a 2 room building with a door and a few dots to be represented as people. So when the simulation starts the people(dots) must go out of the building accordingly. What i need is how to create the UI/simulator. Like some kind of an API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "visual simulator" you mean graphics/drawing engine?

It may or may not fit the bill, but I'm one of the developers of Greenfoot:
http://greenfoot.org/

... which is really an IDE, but it also includes a 2D graphics framework suitable for simple games and simulations. It's open source so if necessary you could rip out the parts you need (as long as you abide by the license terms of course!).

Comment: further explanation added. thanks and i ll look into your IDE as well

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you need is a way to paint 2D content. I would guess that the painting capabilities from java (swing) would be sufficient for you, an OpenGL wrapper or something like that may be overkill.

Look for "Graphics2D, Swing, Animation" ...

Here are some starting links:

- http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Java2D-Tutorial.html
- http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html